# "Safely" Find row in data table with specific field value

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

I'm trying to get a row by using a value from an non pk field "safely"
I can get it to work however I wanted to do it using try and catch so that if the field names does not exist or it can not find any rows with the value it won't crash the app.

However this in turn stuffs up the method as it now states that all pathways don't return a value.

Here is my code:

```
private DataRow getRowByFieldVal(DataSet DtaSet, string sorceTable, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    try
    {
        DataRow[] foundRows = DtaSet.Tables[sorceTable].Select(fieldName + " = " + fieldValue);
        return foundRows[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler is asking `What do you want to return if there is error in try block?`

Imagine a use case.

There is some error in try block so catch starts executing, but since this function has to return something. So what to return in that case. Will it be null or throw exception using `throw`.

So you can do

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    return null; //Add this line.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use try-catch for this. If it does not find a row with the specified value, you can check that with an if. Try-catch is for blocks that could throw an exception. Instead of

```
return foundrows[0];
```

first check if there is any, then return it.

But to answer your question, the catch block needs to return aswell

```
return null;
```

perhaps